# Loading a dropdown with 17000+ values without much delay- asp.net, c#, ajax, jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have a dropdown which needs to be loaded with 17000+ values and when I use regular asp dropdown control, it takes 2-3 seconds to load the values. I have tried using telerik control but that also takes almost the same time. Is there a way I can use jquery ajax to load the values quickly?

Comment: You should change your design. A person will have lots of trouble to quickly find the desired item in a 17.000+ list

Comment: You want a user to select from 17,000 options in a drop-down? That does not sound like good UI design. Consider using two or more drop-downs where the user first selects a category/grouping, then the second drop-down is populated based on the selection in the first one.

Comment: If you think the user experience is bad on your desktop browser, try hitting the page from a mobile browser...

Comment: I've been there with bad design decisions getting thrust onto developers. My suggestion: tell them that if you continue with the suggested design, the page will take those 2-3 seconds to load; that is a technical limitation. Make the suggestions Eric J. and @HyunMi provide, but sometimes it's best to give them the negatives of their decision along with the positives of another. Good luck.

Answer (score 3):

To me it this seems like a scenario where if you have to ask yourself that question you are probably doing something wrong. I suggest instead of using a dropdown to go for something that fits your requirements better. Such as multiple dropdowns ( Category etc). A search box that shows suggestions as a dropdown would be an option as well.

Some resources on the implementation of a textbox with dropdown suggestions:

- http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/
- https://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/documentation

Comment: @EricJ. Do you wish me to elaborate more as to why I consider this a bad design choice? Because having a dropdown with 17000+ options isn't really viable imo.

Comment: Unfortunately,I cannot do any grouping or anything of that sort because they are all organizations and individual organizations. May be I can consider using a search box with suggestions as @HyunMi suggested.

Comment: @ManasaDeepthi Maybe you could group the companies by what industry they are active in for example or where they are based etc.

Comment: @HyunMi I cannot do that because in the first place, I am supposed to have only 1 dropdown for the organizations according to the page design and there is no such grouping I can do.  serchbox with suggestions looks like a good option to me for now.

Comment: @ManasaDeepthi You might find these resources helpful http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/ and https://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/documentation

Comment: In that case, your page design is probably wrong - a single dropdown list on a web page that is supposed to have 17,000 items is just plain bad design. Ask for it to be re-designed using some of the suggestions above, as the current design will make for a bad user experience. Would you want to use it ?

Comment: @EricJ. Fair enough, I did provide references to the implementations using the OP's technology stack though

Comment: this is a follow up question to my previous question. So I replaced dropdown with  a searchbox with suggestions using autocomplete. I am using a .ashx for url. How I debug the .ashx.cs file to see if it is actually loading any values?

Comment: this is a follow up question to my previous question. So I replaced dropdown with  a searchbox with suggestions using autocomplete. I am using a .ashx for url. How I debug the .ashx.cs file to see if it is actually loading any values?

Comment: You will need to either be more specific or make a separate question for that.